# Calling external API from BigQuery

Tags: api, google-bigquery, httprequest

Is it possiple to call external API from BigQuery? What's the best way to do the POST HTTP request from BigQuery?

Comment: You can achieve this through a remote function: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/remote-functions , however keep in mind this is still in preview